# How to get the text in a dynamic text box of a form in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs, forms, textbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

Thank you.
 In my  form there are some dynamic input text boxes created by using ng-repeat. How to get the values of these text boxes when submit the form using Angular js?

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
 <div ng-repeat="opt in option">
  <input type="text" name=""> 
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: More details required. Please show us the code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: <form ng-submit="submit()">
   <div ng-repeat="opt in option">
    <input type="text"  name="">
   </div>
  </form>

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of what you want but guess this will help you

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<input type="text" ng-model="data[$index].Name" ng-repeat="num in numbers track by $index"/>
<p ng-repeat="dataObj in data track by $index">
  {{dataObj.Name}}
</p>
</div>
```

I have created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhil001mehta/jduboz60/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-model to bind the input values and $index for that particular index in the repeated values.

```
 $scope.inputData = [];
```

inputData will have the binded values.

```
 <form ng-submit="submit()">
   <div ng-repeat="opt in option">
     <input type="text" name="" ng-model="inputData[$index]"> 
   </div>
 </form>
```